# Ubuntu installation in virtual box stuck at : (2 of 2) A Start job is run [OK] Reached target sound card

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, 15.10

I've been on this screen for almost 30-40 minutes now, is something wrong with the installation or does it take this much time anyway? What should I do? Also the installation took me almost 80 minutes to reach this screen . I'm tired of waiting :(

Help!

Ubuntu 15.10

Edit : I don't know if its helpful but there are three asterisks in front of : (2 of 2) A Start job is run [OK] Reached target sound card !

And the color of the two asterisks is red like and the middle one is orange like , does it tell anything?